# Particle system not working with geometry nodes

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

I was working on a scene, and I wanted to try the new geometry nodes with rocks. I already had a particle system on the same plane. The problem is, when I enabled the geometry nodes modifier, the particles (grass) didn't show up any more. I think the the reason why it doesn't work is because the particle system isn't part of the mesh. I could convert the particle system to mesh, but that will just kill my computer and the pebbles will probably also go on top of the grass. So I want to know if there's a way to add the particle system in the geometry node modifier, or maybe you have another way!

So my question in short: "**how can I add the particle system to the object while also having a geometry node modifier active?**"

Thanks in advance!

Ravi

Answer (score 1):

The particle system is a modifier. Make sure it happens after the geometry nodes modifier. Then check the box under the 'source' expander of particle nodes tab that says "Use Modifier Stack"

[image]